# How to Delete Clear or Omit Word's Table of Contents Using Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I'm trying to covert word documents to an alternative format.  The preexisting table of contents (TOC) creates problems.  Because there are nearly a hundred or so documents, I want to use powershell to iterate over the files and clear the TOC. There are posts on how to [insert](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/01/04/creating-a-table-of-contents-in-word-using-powershell/) and [update](https://superuser.com/questions/1397014/powershell-update-refresh-the-toc-of-a-word-document) the TOC using powershell. One post suggested proceeding in this fashion which partially works.

```
$filename = "example.docx"
#create object
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
#watch changes
$word.Visible = $true
#open doc
$doc = $word.documents.open($filename)
$doc.TablesOfContent.Item(1).Delete()
$doc.save()
$doc.close()
```

The problem is that the TOC is empty but still present, with a "Contents" header and a shaded box.  Microsoft does document the `TablesOfContents` object on its [website](https://superuser.com/questions/1397014/powershell-update-refresh-the-toc-of-a-word-document) under VBA.  Struggling for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `@TheMadTechnician` provides an excellent comment on it.

Pls try.

```
$filename = "D:\temp\example.docx"
#create object
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
#watch changes
$word.Visible = $true
#open doc
$doc = $word.documents.open($filename)
$doc.TablesOfContents.Item(1).Delete()
foreach ($para in $doc.Paragraphs) {
    if ($para.style.NameLocal -match "TOC") {
        $para.Range.Delete()
        break
        }}
foreach ($para in $doc.Paragraphs) { 
    if ($para.Range.Text -eq [char]13) {
            $para.Range.Delete()
        } else {
            break
        }}              
$doc.save()
$doc.close()
```

Comment: that would delete any paragraph with the word "contents" in it.  Maybe try `$para.style.NameLocal -match 'TOC '` instead. That would just find things formatted with the Table of Contents formatting style.

Comment: I was convinced that I was using the "Item(1)" portion of the code incorrectly.  Many thanks for the solution!